# jQuery loop to create google_tag_params

Tags: jquery, google-ads-api

I am looping thru an array I created that grabs product elements, I am getting no errors but it is not building the tag params. I verified that I am getting the data, I think i'm missing something though, total jQuery newbie here :(

```
 var productsString = JSON.stringify(products, null, 4);


     var google_tag_params = "{" +     

        $.each(productsString,  function(key, value){

            "ecomm_prodid :" + value.ecomm_prodid;
            "ecomm_pagetype :" + value.ecomm_pagetype;
            "ecomm_totalvalue :" + value.ecomm_totalvalue;
        }


        )

        +           
    "};";
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1030976867;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /* ]]> */
    });
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I used your code and it's doing the same thing mine was, the variable doesn't print out the results it just displays as text.

```
here is what gets spit out in the source:  

     var google_tags = "var google_tag_params = {";   

    $.each(productsString,  function(key, value){

        google_tags += "ecomm_prodid :" + value.ecomm_prodid;
        google_tags += "ecomm_pagetype :" + value.ecomm_pagetype;
        google_tags += "ecomm_totalvalue :" + value.ecomm_totalvalue;
    })

    google_tags += "};";

    /* <![CDATA[ */

    google_tags;
    var google_conversion_id = 1030976867;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /* ]]> */
    });
```

**EDIT**

End result is this tag with around 12 products info in the params field

```
<!--Google Dynamic Remarketing Script  -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var google_tag_params = **{
        ecomm_prodid: '41428368',
        ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
        ecomm_totalvalue: '1,974.99'
    };**
</script>
```

so basically there will be 12 iterations of the 3 variables ID, pagettype and totalvalue.

Comment: I don't think I understand. What printing are you referring to?

Comment: It is just showing the name of the variable, not the values of it. I am trying to dynamically build a script tag for google.

Comment: Where are you trying to build a script tag? I don't see that in this code. Are you just expecting JavaScript variables to somehow magically appear in the DOM?

Comment: I have to build the google dynamic retargeting paramaters based on class elements on the page which can and will change. the google_tag_params section can take an array which is what I am getting but I cannot get the tag to work.

Comment: There are no html tags in the code you have provided. Your comments make no sense to me.

Comment: I might be going about this the wrong way I'll edit the question again and show you what I need to build. I am basically pulling in 12 different products info, ID , price and pagetype ( which is static ). Putting this into an array and then I need to build the google script tag with the params being dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine all of the product IDs into an array and use *that* as the value for ecomm_prodid.  There should only ever be one google_tag_params assignment, not multiple (unless you are doing something crazy with multiple firings of the tag which probably isn't a good idea...)

For example, say you had your 12 products.  For the sake of clarity lets say that the IDs are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.

This is what you want to get to:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var google_tag_params = {
        ecomm_prodid: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
        ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
        ecomm_totalvalue: 1974.99
    };
</script>
```

Note that the ecomm_totalvalue should be a sum of the values of all products that are in the ecomm_prodid array, and should be a normal Number and not a string (no commas, no $ or £ etc)

So, something like this:

```
var products = [{'id':'1','price':9.99},{'id':'2','price':4.99}];

var ids = [];
var total = 0;

$.each(products,  function(key, value){
  ids.push(value.id);
  total += Number(value.price);
});

var google_tag_params = {
  ecomm_prodid: ids,
  ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
  ecomm_totalvalue: total
};
```

This would then be equivalent of something like this:

```
var google_tag_params = {
  ecomm_prodid: ["1", "2"],
  ecomm_pagetype: "product",
  ecomm_totalvalue: 14.98
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not seeing how this tag can be formed on document.ready. Is it even possible to do this client side? I have all the values but the tag cant be formed simultaneously. I am using asp.net is there a way to grab this from document.ready in lets say page load and have the tag spit out in a literal tag? So far I haven't been able to grab these values in the code behind I'm not sure which fires first, document.ready or page_load

Comment: If you are using a server-side stuff, just pre-build the javascript code on the server.  The documentation tells you everything you need: https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/ (scroll down to dynamic remarketing tab, then in that tab scroll down to ASP.net section)

Comment: That's the rub... These values aren't available server side, its a 3rd party search engine that is just a usercontrol tag. I need to grab these client side and somehow generate the tag server side or client if that's even possible.

Comment: So somehow I need to grab the prod id's and total server side and generate the tag, not sure what event server side will allow for me to get these and create the tag by the time the page is done loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
var google_tag_params = "{";   

$.each(productsString,  function(key, value){

    google_tag_params += "ecomm_prodid :" + value.ecomm_prodid;
    google_tag_params += "ecomm_pagetype :" + value.ecomm_pagetype;
    google_tag_params += "ecomm_totalvalue :" + value.ecomm_totalvalue;
}

google_tag_params += "};";
```

You are not trying to build JSON right? This will not construct valid JSON, but I assume that is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: No it's just a format that google takes for params it looks like google_tag_params = { ecoom_prodid: 'value', ecomm_pagetype: 'value', ecomm_totalvalue : 'value'}. I did an alert on the google-params and it's spitting it out correct just not building the tag. I'm thinking im missing something simple.

Comment: @chromeOne7 Wait, so my code does not do what you want? If not can you provide what you expect the string to be after the code runs.